# Can not hover to select the last symbol

Tags: reactjs, echarts, echarts-for-react

Draw a line chart using `echarts` library. The length of each data array is 1248. The mouse cannot hover to select the last point(symbol). The date of the last point should be today(`2023-10-13`), but I can only hover to select the point whose date is `2023-10-09`.

[image]

```
import React from "react";
import ReactEcharts from "echarts-for-react";
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import { data } from "./data";

export const PeriodOptions = ["1Y", "2Y", "3Y", "5Y", "7Y"];

const fields = [
    { key: "ytm7Ys", color: "#B2B2B2" },
    { key: "ytm5Ys", color: "#FF8A5E " },
    { key: "ytm3Ys", color: "#F0C390" },
    { key: "ytm2Ys", color: "#23B899" },
    { key: "ytm1Ys", color: "#808CFF" },
];
const periodNames = PeriodOptions.slice().reverse();
const option = {
    xAxis: {
        type: "category",
        data: data.issueDates.map((date) => dayjs(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD")),
        axisLabel: { showMaxLabel: true },
    },
    yAxis: {},
    series: fields.map((f, i) => ({
        data: (data as any)[f.key] ?? [],
        name: periodNames[i],
        color: f.color,
        type: "line",
        lineStyle: {
            width: 1,
        },
        showSymbol: false,
        connectNulls: true,
        animation: false,
    })) as any[],
    tooltip: {
        trigger: "axis",
        padding: 5,
    },
};

export default function App() {
    return (
        <div style={{ width: 450, marginTop: 100 }}>
            <ReactEcharts option={option} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

You can see the data in the example:

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/echarts-cant-hover-last-symbol-prwh6l)